# What ML/DL techniques power Youtube/Netflix search systems?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, search-engine

Video platforms like YouTube, Netflix, Amazon prime have an excellent search system - given a search string, find most relevant videos. Which Machine Learning /Deep Learning techniques used for this?

Any pointers will be of great help

Comment: Make the question as pointed as possible.  Image-search, music search and vid search mostly have a different kind of implementations. So, limit your qn to a single use-case to get better, to-the-point answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

At **Netflix**, the machine ​learning algorithms used are more complex since the data is really vast and increases day to day. Take a look at these:

[Netflix Recommendations: Beyond the 5 stars (Part 1)](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/netflix-recommendations-beyond-the-5-stars-part-1-55838468f429)

[Machine Learning Is Everywhere: Netflix, Personalized Medicine, and Fraud Prevention | Udacity](http://blog.udacity.com/2016/06/machine-learning-everywhere-netflix-personalized-medicine-fraud-prevention.html)

Comment: the blog is a 2012 blog. I am looking for more recent DL approaches!

Answer (score 0):

The technical term is "recommender system." The biggest problem in recommender systems is the sparsity and size of the data. All algorithms beyond nearest neighbor search for latent features in the same way as PCA. Most common ones are k nearest neighbor and Singular value decomposition. I have seen lstm used to interesting effect though it would follow user's current focus rather than all items they like. movix.ai For more info sign up for movielens.org and see how they describe their algorithms. Very thorough list of interesting recommendation sites: https://alternativeto.net/list/2554/recommender-systems-apps-for-the-end-user-